# Why am I getting Type Error on list += but it works on list.append()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm picking up programming on python, am learning how to create basic caesar cypher and ran across the rather common

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I've taken a look around and found out what the type error means but out of curiosity I tried if the code would work with list.append and surprisingly it did. Now I'm puzzled because I thought list.append and list += could be used similarly for adding to a list, below is part of the code that works when using list.append. What's the difference with how these two work or interpreted?

```
text_to_list = list(text)
list_to_number = []
for letter in text_to_list:
    cipher_num = alphabet.index(letter)
    list_to_number.append(cipher_num)
```

Comment: `+=` works for adding another *list* (or other iterable) to a list, not for adding a single item to a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Comment: It does, thank you very much! Although it does lead me towards another question. To clarify, that means using += on a list is the same as list.extend, which basically concatenates an iterable to an existing list yes? On the execution side, what makes the using += on a list different to let's say using a += to increase the value of a variable? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, you may find the answers to these new questions here on the site, or if not you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between += and list.append() is that += is used to extend a list by adding values from another list, while append adds a value to the end of the list.

**Examples**

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.append(3) # now a = [1, 2, 3, 3]

b = [1, 2, 3]
b += [3] # now b = [1, 2, 3, 3]

c = [1, 2, 3]
c += 3 # TypeError

d = [1, 2, 3]
d.append([3]) # now d = [1, 2, 3, [3]]
```

There is a built in list method, .extend(), which behaves the same as +=.

```
e = [1, 2, 3]
e.extend([3]) # now e = [1, 2, 3, 3]

f = [1, 2, 3]
f.extend(3) # TypeError
```